# Oracle unpivot multiple columns equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, unpivot

I am able to convert an Oracle `unpivot` query with one column name in the unpivot clause to Postgres(using lateral). But I'm unable to do it when the unpivot query has more than one column.

**Case 1: (with one column in unpivot clause which I'm able to convert as below)**

***Oracle:***

```
SELECT id, col_name, date FROM foo
UNPIVOT include nulls((date)
    FOR col_name
    IN (a AS 'A', 
        b AS 'B',
        c as 'C'));
```

***Postgres equivalent:***

```
SELECT id, col_name, date
FROM foo
, LATERAL (VALUES('A', a),('B', b),('C',c)) s(col_name, date);
```

**Case 2: (Needs help)**
But when the Oracle unpivot has more than one column as below, I don't know how to convert it to Postgres.

***Oracle:***

```
WITH cte AS
            (SELECT  MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS MIN_DATE,MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS MAX_DATE, id ,dt_ref.dp_id
                   FROM idd_eom, dt_ref
                   GROUP BY id ,dt_ref.dp_id)
           select id, dp_id, dp_code, min_date, max_date
           FROM cte UNPIVOT ((min_date, max_date)
                         FOR dp_code
                         IN  ( (MIN_DATE ,MAX_DATE ) AS 'EFFECTIVE_DATE'));
```

***Postgres equivalent:***  ??

Please help to convert the above to Postgres using lateral or cross join lateral or unnest.

Comment: Your second query doesn't look valid. Describe your table and show real valid query

Comment: Tuple in the `unpivot` needs to have the same number of elements as each tuple in `in` clause has. It is not the case for you, because unpivoted tuple has two elements, but tuples in `in` have only one element

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, i have edited the query.

Comment: @Manoharan still strange query.. Describe your table, provide few rows and what do you want to get. Show working  example what do you have originally and what you want to get. You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/ with your working Oracle data and queries that you want to convert to Postgres

Comment: and I would suggest to do not use `date` since it's a reserved word in oracle.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov added the original query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited as suggested by you.

Comment: show us some sample data & expected output please

Comment: `Unpivot` with single tuple has nothing to do with unpivot, because you may just add constant column as `dp_code` and rename unpivoting columns via `as`

Comment: @astentx, if you don't mind, can you please show me how to convert it to postgres as per what you said?